# Google Play orders made through in-app billing cannot be charged

Tags: android, in-app-billing, google-checkout

I have added in-app billing to my app, and everything seems to work fine on the Android side. But the orders in Google Checkout cannot be charged, even though the status is chargeable, because the Charge Order button is disabled. Apart from this, everything about the order appears to be correct.

The same thing happens with the Dungeons sample app, so I am a bit stuck at this point.

Answer (score 1):

You give very little informations about your problem.

What is the purchase type you're using ? If they are "managed per user account", then they can only be purchased once for a given user. Maybe the charge has been successful once, and is now blocked (in which case you should use "unmanaged" purchases)

Or maybe I'm totally wrong, and you should give us some additional infos.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Google will block you from charging unless your app is published or you register your self as a test user.

Test users can parches when the app is not published.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the Charge button when selling Android apps. Charging occurs automatically.

Maybe the Charge button is there for other kind of goods sold on Google Play, but for software sales it's useless, thus it's grayed.

Answer (score 0):

Worth a general read: [In-app Billing](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/index.html).

On the Google checkout side of things, one potential cause for this issue is that there is a delay period with purchases for fraud detection, etc. (source ["Charge Order" button greyed out](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/checkout-merchant/Zk-q33phkhw)). More reading on this here: [In-app billing and Google Checkout setup](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/wBCXZa--xtI). It is typical for the "charge order" button to be greyed out during this period.

I'm guessing that this isn't your issue however, because it would have been resolved already. In [can't press charge order button but order is chargeable](https://www.google.com/search?q=google+android+charge+order&sugexp=chrome,mod=11&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) one of the most relevant points is given as

> @sounddoctorin: If you click the order details, you will see why - its likely the order is in some pending state "Reviewing", etc.
>
> The point is that if you can't click the "Charge" button, it means the order is still pending for one reason or another.

For more information on charge states visit ["Understanding Order States"](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Basic_HTML_Order_States).

If this still doesn't help resolve your issue I would look into figuring out why it is misbehaving. What other data can you gather?